# How to get the value of the text property which is setted by dynamic resource in a template?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dynamicresource

I'm facing problem in the `.XAML` part, there is template with a `textblock` which the value of text property is setted by dynamic resource. In the `.CS`, I don't know how to get the value of the text property. With the following code,just get a empty string.

```
DependencyObject tempObject = varDataGrid.Columns[i].HeaderTemplate.LoadContent();
(tempObject as TextBlock).Text.ToString();
```

Give some suggestions, Thanks!

Comment: I have already set a code block for you:) FYI, all the functionality is above the 'text-area', which includes 'BOLD', 'ITALY', 'HORIZONTAL LINE', etc... 'Welcome to StackOverflow' :)

Comment: @Roylee, you might care to know that [you're being discussed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137938/can-we-have-a-pointless-edit-or-depressing-waste-of-human-effort-for-some-rep).

Answer (score 0):

> the value of text property is setted by dynamic resource

Assuming you have this text as a resource, then in the code behind you should be able to call this.FindResource("yourResourceKey") using the same resource key you used in your markup, and it should resolve to the same type as your resource.  For example:

```
string text = (string)this.FindResource("yourResourceKey");
```

If this is not what you are doing, please post your XAML code where you define the template and the resource.